# Divide string up and eliminate certain key value pairs in PHP

Tags: php

I have a string that, when divided up by its only delimited ("="), comes out to be in the following form:

```
time0 -> 2016-03-18T01:33:52Z
time1 -> 2016-03-18T00:25:54Z
timezone0 -> GMT
timezone1 -> GMT
type0 -> Subscription
type1 -> General
email1 -> email@email.com
name0 -> first
name1 -> second
tr0 -> ###
tr1 -> ###
st0 -> Created
st1 -> Completed
amt1 -> 19.95
currency1 -> USD
fee1 -> -0.88
net1 -> 19.07
```

Here is the code for it ($result holds the full string):

```
foreach($result as $value){
    $value = explode("=", $value);
    print $value[0] . " -> " .$value[1] . "<br/>";
}
```

As you can see, there are 2 types of categories, one which is "Subscription" and one which is "General". What I am essentially looking to do is filter out for only a specific type. For example, if I am looking for type "Subscription", then the output should be as follows:

```
time0 -> 2016-03-18T01:33:52Z
timezone0 -> GMT
type0 -> Subscription
name0 -> first
tr0 -> ###
st0 -> Created
```

If there were multiple types with "subscription" (e.g. `type0` and `type2` were "Subscription"), then it would return the `time0` and `type2`, `timezone0` and `timezone2`, `tr0` and `tr2` etc.

Is this possible?

Comment: looks like you need to find index for the type corresponding your subscription, and get the same indexed values, looks straightforward to me. Is it an xml in the beginning?

Comment: Nope, the original string is like this: `time0=2016%2d03%2d18T01%3a33%3a52Z&time1=2016...`. You have to figure out for which keys is the value "Subscription", then record the number  at the end of that key, then run through the entire key value array to only select where the number at the end of the key is one of the recorded ones.

Comment: Oh ok then. You already gave the solution )) What stops you from doing it? First get index for the type with subscription, `$index = substr($typstring,4);` now you have it, retrieve all other keys with the same index at the end. Repeat this for every type where Subscription is present.

Comment: you're perhaps looking for http://php.net/parse_str ?